# Flexibility of Scala's Actor Model

Tags: scala, actor, akka

I've been using actor based programming model with Microsoft's [Asynchronous Agents library for C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492627.aspx).
Having started experimenting with Scala, it seems to me that its model is not that rich as in Asynchronous Agents. For example Async Agent provides a lot of different Asynchronous Message Blocks which can be combined in different ways to make network of agents.
How does this map to Scala's native actors, or actors using Akka?

Comment: I think you need to refine your question. What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Well, I am not looking into solution for some particular problem, rather a comparison between two frameworks, since both are based on similar model

Comment: Well, Akka has Akka Routing, Akka Future Composition and Akka Camel Integration (complete with Camel routing etc), so Akka can integrate with > 80 different protocols and can build up complex networks of Actors and do transformations etc, even using remote actors, so on several nodes. But you don't really define "rich" so I don't know if I'm answering the question or not.

Answer (score 0):

Scala has something called a "case class" that can be used to define any number of message types. As for behaviors, that is what actors are for. The things defined here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504833.aspx all sound like behaviors to me, and most would be simple to implement with an actor.